# Qlik Sense If Statement Expression with Email

Tags: qliksense

I have a table that has to have a email link in it from a IF Else statement. I can get the email to work fine but when I have the IF Else statement included, I get a invalid dimension. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
=IF(45-(networkdays(max({<[Access Type]={'User Access', 'Login Access'}>} Date),Today())) = 15,

'mailto:'&EMAIL_ADDRESS&'?subject=Your QLIKSENSE Account has become DISABLED'&'&body= This is a NOTICE informing you that your Qlik Sense account has been disabled due to inactivity. 

You will have 15 days to log into your account before the account is deleted. 

All inactive accounts will be DELETED after 45 days of inactivity.

To access the Qlik Sense site, navigate to https://website and click Get Started.
')
,
IF(45-(networkdays(max({<[Access Type]={'User Access', 'Login Access'}>} Date),Today())) <= 5,

'mailto:'&EMAIL_ADDRESS&'?subject=Your QLIKSENSE Account has been deleted'&'&body= This is a NOTICE informing you that your Qlik Sense account has been deleted due to inactivity. 

All inactive accounts will be DELETED after 45 days of inactivity.

To access the Qlik Sense site, navigate to https://website and click Get Started.
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing *'* after the last Point ("Get Started.')". Last *)* isn't opened at the beginning.